# Created a game where the Frame's width is accurate after I run it but the height never updates

Tags: java

I'm learning to make games using a a tutorial on youtube. Everything seems fine except when I run the program. A frame shows up with the accurate width I want but the height looks like it sets to a default no matter what value I give it.

```
package ca.vanzeben.game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;

    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static final int WIDTH = 160;
        public static final int Height = WIDTH/ 12*9;
        public static final int SCALE = 3; // able to move screen 
        public static final String NAME = "Juego";

        private JFrame frame;

        public boolean running = false;
        public int tickCount = 0;

        private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        public Game() {         //game constructor
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));

            frame = new JFrame(NAME);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // closes game completely 
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


            frame.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER); //adds canvas to JFrame and centers it 
            frame.pack();//keeps everything sized correctly 

            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }


        public synchronized void start() {//so u can start from the applet 
            running = true;
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        public synchronized void stop(){
            running = false;
        }

        public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000.0/60; //nanoseconds per tick or per update 

        int ticks = 0;
        int frames = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0.0; //how many unprocessed nano seconds 

        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta+=(now-lastTime)/nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean shouldRender = true;

            while(delta>=1){
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;

            }
        try{
        Thread.sleep(2);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            if(shouldRender){
            frames++;
            render();
            }


        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimer>=1000){

        lastTimer += 1000;
        System.out.println(frames + " frames " + ticks + " ticks ");
        frames = 0;
        ticks = 0;

            }
            }
        }


        public void tick(){ //updates the game, updates the logic
            tickCount++;
            for(int i =0;i<pixels.length;i++){
                pixels[i] = i + tickCount;
            }
        }

        public void render(){ //prints out ^
            BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
            if(bs == null){
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }
            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.dispose();
            bs.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Game().start();
        }



    }
```

Comment: Please clarify and illustrate what your issue is, specifically what code it is you believe is causing the issue, and what you have tried thus far to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `Height` and used `HEIGHT`. Change it to:

```
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
```

This is how it looked like to me:

*Before*:

[image: Before]

*After*:

[image: After]

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it.

Comment: If this solved your issue, set it as an answer to avoid more replies.